# Centos :: Can't delete / remove package for updating

Tags: php, centos, package, php-gd

On my server I'm running PHP 5.5.1. I would like to install PHP-GD. But when I trying to install it, it always says:
**http://pastie.org/private/suerkbk7ogbuj5mtpduo7w**

it seems that the php-gd package is available on the server for php 5.3.
I can't delete or removed it from the server. I'll always receive this message: **Package(s) php-gd available, but not installed.**

Can someone help me with this?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: If you don't get a response here you might try http://serverfault.com/

Comment: Thanks! I'll add the question also there.